# Problem with gaesessions (django+GAE)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using gaesessions on gae with django. When I run the application Following error occurs while loading `gaesessions.DjangoSessionMiddleware`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4053, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3977, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 588, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3050, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2954, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 2836, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    script_module.main()
  File "D:\projects\tutorial\selftutor.py", line 35, in main
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 98, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 116, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 252, in __call__
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "D:\projects\tutorial\gaesessions\__init__.py", line 493, in process_response
    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\utils\cache.py", line 127, in patch_vary_headers
    if response.has_header('Vary'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you using the webapp framework?

Comment: No, I'm using django 1.2 with GAE. Any ways I found the prolem. In my earlier 'Middleware' response was None and same object is passed in here. Thanks.

Comment: @Shwetanka, if you found the problem, please post it as an answer and close out the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware does not get handed a response. Check your request handler.